# ComboBox SelectedItem display

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

The binding below gets and sets the selected item. It also displays items correctly, which in this case just means displaying a department's name.

However, instead of displaying the selected department name, it displays the selected department's ToString().

How can I fix this so the selected item displays only the department name?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
<ComboBox 
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"

    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Departments}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Department, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
/>
```

Comment: "instead of displaying the selected department name, it displays the selected department's ToString(). " can u please explain more on this

Comment: Please post your solution as a proper answer and accept it, answers do not belong into the question and that way it looks like an answer is needed from the outside which is not the case.

Comment: @H.B. - It is a 'fix', if somewhat short of a "proper" answer tho. I like using DataTemplate quite a lot now so gave up on the DisplayMemberPath style. But it should have worked, no? Can you see any reason that it didn't? Cheers

Comment: I don't know, it normally works for me as expected, there might be some bug in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because .Net framework calls the `ToString()` method on each observable collection item. To solve this problem you can override `ToString()` method in your Model like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

Comment: how to update when name changed?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by changing the DisplayMemberPath to a DataTemplate as shown below.

Although I'm not sure why the DisplayMemberPath didn't work here, I have to assume there was some other bug in my code somewhere. Being an old question, the code has since changed and isn't worth recreating.

As an aside, I routinely use DataTemplates now, even for simple cases like this one.

Cheers,
Berryl

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```